# Is there any method so that I can enter different values in different entry box of one label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter-entry

I am working on a project and want some help regarding entries in tkinter.I have to put different values in different entry boxes for same label.Means I have created one save button which stores the values of one product in one entry box and one reset button for storing the values of second product.Then how can I store the information of second product in second entry box of same label with first entries remain unaffected??

Comment: Does your reset button resets your First Entry Box while storing the value of Second, can you breakdown your Query or provide related code.

Comment: no,reset button does not resets the first entries. Those entries remain unaffected due to reset button. The reset button is for resetting the information in another  box for entering the information of second product which i have to store in the second entry box after first values

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially export all the information to a file and then re-import it when you click another button. I have an example of this code used for a different project I did in school.

First you want to create a button that links to a function.

```
tkinter.Button(self, text='Open File', command=self.open)
tkinter.Button(self, text='Save File', command=self.save)
```

Afterwards you want to open/save all the information by reading/writing it with a file.

```
//Opening Files
def open(self):
    file_info = []
    ftypes = [('All Files', "*.*")]
         ttl = "Open Flash Cards"
         dir1 = 'C:\\'
         fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=ftypes, initialdir=dir1, title=ttl)
         with open(fname, 'r') as file:
              num_lines = (sum(1 for line in file)) //Gets num of lines in file
              for x in range(num_lines):
                   file_info.append(file.readline().rstrip())

//Saving Files
def save(self):
       ftype = [('Text files', '*.txt*', 'TEXT')]
       dir1 = 'C:\\'
       ttl = 'Save'
       fname = asksaveasfilename(confirmoverwrite=False,
                                     filetypes= ftype,
                                     initialdir= dir1,
                                     initialfile= base,
                                     title = ttl,
                                     defaultextension='.txt')
       if fname:
             with open(fname, 'w') as file:
                  f.write("Information goes here")
```

Essentially the *save function* will save information line by line from a '.txt' file.

Whilst the *open function* will grab information line by line from a '.txt' file and append it to **file_info**.